# Bash filesname pattern detection and correction

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching

I'm looking for the tools to detect a pattern in multiple files with the purpose to correct any heterogeneity. Precisely, this tool would help to generate the renaming scheme.
A correct pattern would be a mix of fixed patterns and increments followed by whatever and then an authorized extension.

Number of files ranges from 10 000 to 100 000, the solution should aim to minimize user intervention.

I have a directory like this :

```
  testDir/
├── corrupttestfile100.ext
├── testfil0000.ext
├── testfil0001.ext
├── testfil0002.ext
├── testfil0003.ext
├── testfil0004.ext
├── testfil0005.ext
├── testfil0006.ext
├── testfil0007.ext
├── testfil0008.ext
├── testfil0009.ext
├── testfile010.ext
├── testfile011.ext
├── testfile012.ext
├── testfile013.ext
├── testfile014.ext
├── testfile015.ext
├── testfile016.ext
├── testfile017.ext
├── testfile018.ext
├── testfile019.ext
├── testfile020.ext
├── testfile021.ext
├── testfile022.ext
├── testfile023.ext
├── testfile024.ext
├── testfile025.ext
├── testfile026.ext
├── testfile027.ext
├── testfile028.ext
├── testfile029.ext
├── testfile030.ext
├── testfile031.ext
├── testfile032.ext
├── testfile033.ext
├── testfile034.ext
├── testfile035.ext
├── testfile036.ext
├── testfile037.ext
├── testfile038.ext
├── testfile039.ext
├── testfile040.ext
├── testfile041.ext
├── testfile042.ext
├── testfile043.ext
├── testfile044.ext
├── testfile045.ext
├── testfile046.ext
├── testfile047.ext
├── testfile048.ext
├── testfile049.ext
├── testfile050.ext
├── testfile051.ext
├── testfile052.ext
├── testfile053.ext
├── testfile054.ext
├── testfile055.ext
├── testfile056.ext
├── testfile057.ext
├── testfile058.ext
├── testfile059.ext
├── testfile060.ext
├── testfile061.ext
├── testfile062.ext
├── testfile063.ext
├── testfile064.ext
├── testfile065.ext
├── testfile066.ext
├── testfile067.ext
├── testfile068.ext
├── testfile069.ext
├── testfile080.ext
├── testfile081.ext
├── testfile082.ext
├── testfile083.ext
├── testfile084.ext
├── testfile085.ext
├── testfile086.ext
├── testfile087.ext
├── testfile088.ext
├── testfile089.ext
├── testfile090.ext
├── testfile091.ext
├── testfile092.ext
├── testfile093.ext
├── testfile094.ext
├── testfile095.ext
├── testfile096.ext
├── testfile097.ext
├── testfile098.ext
├── testfile099.ext
├── testfile101.ext2
└── testfileNotRelevant.ext
```

And I'd like to have the adequate tools to produce following feedback or equivalent :

```
  1. pattern ^testfil matching 92/93

        Exception : 
        corrupttestfile100.ext

  2. pattern ^testfile matching 82/93

        Exception :
        corrupttestfile100.ext
        testfil0000.ext
        testfil0001.ext
        testfil0002.ext
        testfil0003.ext
        testfil0004.ext
        testfil0005.ext
        testfil0006.ext
        testfil0007.ext
        testfil0008.ext
        testfil0009.ext

 3. Increment pattern breaks [70-79]
 4. Increment pattern 3 digits 92/93
 5. Increment pattern 4 digits 10/93
 6. Extension exception : ext2 1/93
```

I began to scrip in bash using grep, find, sed and rename as it seemed natural but I'm wondering if will hit some walls and if I'm reinventing the wheel. I don't seem to find any relevant source of help and similar existing tools aren't open source nor data agnostic.

Comment: `correct any heterogeneity`, bit vague. Also have you even started to attempt to solve this ?

Comment: What more information do you need? The examples from "following feedback" gives a nice depiction of what I call heterogeneity. And yes I did but it's not effective and I must adapt for almost every batch of files.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Good luck with your question.

Comment: Mmmh, I see precisely what I want to do, I may lack the how thou. I suppose I will come back when I have a first draft of my solution. I just hoped something already existed. I did already processed +- 500k files...